# Set server timezone but not working with crontab and phpmyadmin

Tags: cron, phpmyadmin

## TimeZone is not working properly

I am using linode server running ubuntu 12.04LTS. My Question is when i configured timezone by using dpkg reconfigure tz as IST ASIA/Calcutta. It shows correct timezone by using date command. But it is not working in CRON jobs and PHPMYADMIN. Because My work is very important, anxiously i have to work in UTC timezone to run my cron jobs accordingly. But now i am  stucking with my applications output run by cron jobs. Please help me!!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

It will work after you restart crontab. Better to restart the system. otherwise you have to restart too many services. like syslog will also show old time zone, until you restart it.
Mean while below commands will resolve your problem.

> $ service cron restart
>
> $ sudo service rsyslog restart

Comment: this works for me

Answer (score 0):

Please set your timezone using `sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`  instead of via an environment variable.

Comment: timezone is not set permanently after set link to /etc/localtime, so i did export and its done but not working woth crontab and phpmyadmin